# Remote mysql only works from my computer, but no others

Tags: mysql, remote

I need a direct connection to a MySQL server on a remote web server. So I've added to cpanel access hosts list an IP of the computer I wish to connect to the remote web server. But I can't connect, tried: telnet remote IP 3306, but no luck. I've tried on several computers with no luck. Only from my computer, it works. Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**:

I've contacted hosting company and they confirmed that they have firewall on, but how on Earth I could connect from my computer then? I think it will remain a mystery...

Comment: You have usually a firewall, that would block every access to teh mysql server. there you must open the port. But caution it os never a good idea to connect a mysql serv direct to the internet, it will be attacked immediately, that why most developer implement a rest api and connect via http only. for configuration of server exist also a sister site serverfaut.

Comment: "Am I missing something?" A lot of details for sure. Find what is different between "my computer" and the other "several computers".

Comment: @mustaccio sorry for such short details I've posted, but it is just like that when I put address of my computer in remote access hosts it work, but it doesn't work from the computer it should work. Of course I put that IP address there too, like something else is blocking it.

Answer (score 1):

1. you must be have user with host `%` and grant level like root user
2. You can test telnet or remote mysql from cpanel server **if success** networking or firewall issue is solved because your mysql server can access from other client. **if not** you must be check from networking level and firewall level probably default port mysql is blocked.

Comment: Thanks @febry we will contact hosting provider today because I am sure that day know more about this